Stuck filtering a collection of <tr>s to return the sibling <td>, matching on the <tr> textContent
Im scraping a table and getting all its immediate 's
const trs = tableDom.querySelectorAll("table#TableID tbody > tr");

I'm having trouble then filtering over these 's. I'm trying to find the right row by matching the  content of a row, when I match the row I return the sibling  (there is only ever 1  in the ).
First I'm spreading the returned tableDom (NodeList) into an js array, then using .filter(). Like so.
const td = [...tableDom].filter((row) => row.querySelector("th").textContent == "string to match" && row.querySelector("td").textContent);

This only returns the  e.g. [tr].
I beleive its because of the conversion to array thats its failing. Is there a better way to perform this matching/filtering?
